# how to reduce space gap between multiple graphs in R

Tags: r

```
var8    p_1 p_2 p_3
1   6617    6635    6739
2   6563    6668    6699
3   6711    6695    6782
4   6807    6863    6753
5   6996    7035    7044
6   7221    7336    7201
7   7236    7198    7224
8   7307    7475    7357
9   7230    7281    7165
10  7152    7162    6935
11  7295    7116    6805
12  6923    6852    6565
1   6854    6705    6537
2   6724    6685    6589
3   6815    6715    6656
4   6933    6876    6805
5   7183    7104    7042
6   7361    7302    7402
7   7383    7401    7388
8   7389    7377    7377
9   7315    7346    7375
10  7287    7249    7337
11  6923    7059    7238
12  6884    6862    6958
1   6711    6728    6829
2   6680    6724    
3   6806    6774    6696
4   6756    6831    6943
5   7091    7074    7108
6   7364    7326    7147
7   7314    7390    7214
8   7326    7379    7262
9   7278    7316    7201
10  7283    7350    7240
11  7133    7160    7102
12  6916    6879    6971
1   6727    6673    6826
2   6662    6683    6793
3   6701    6713    6884
4   6923    6812    7042
5   7075    7056    7189
6   7183    7269    7324
7   7324        7450
8   7361    7353    7464
9   7392    7253    7326
10  7264    7171    7315
11  7108    7017    7244
12  6750    6949    6985
1   6640    6843    6859
2   6724    6728    6854
3   6642    6797    6877
4   6800    6895    6921
5   6991    7002    7232
6   7288    7211    7389
7   7371    7272    7468
8   7333    7270    7618
9   7230    7125    7443
10  7147    6973    7510
11  7203    6840    7396
12  7013    6758    7144


d = read.table()
lmts <- range(d)
par(mfrow=c(1,3))
colors = c(rep("skyblue",1), rep("skyblue1",1), rep("skyblue2", 1), rep("skyblue3", 1), rep("mediumpurple1", 1), rep("mediumpurple", 1), rep("mediumpurple3", 1), rep("royalblue1",1), rep("slateblue1", 1), rep("slateblue3", 1), rep("slategray3",1), rep("slategray1",1))
boxplot(p_1~var8, ylim=c(6500,7650), col=colors, outline = FALSE, 
        lty=1, las=2, ylab = "Mean(mm)", cex.lab=1, cex.axis=1, boxwex=0.65, xaxt='n')
axis(1, at=c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12), labels=c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"), cex.axis=1, las=1)


boxplot(p_3~var8, boxcol= FALSE, col=colors,  
        lty=1, las=2, xlab="Months of year", cex.lab=1, cex.axis=1, outline = FALSE, boxwex=0.65, xaxt='n', yaxt='n')
axis(1, at=c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12), labels=c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"), cex.axis=1, las=1)


boxplot(p_2~var8, boxcol= FALSE, col=colors,  
        lty=1, las=2, cex.lab=1, cex.axis=1, outline = FALSE, boxwex=0.65, xaxt='n', yaxt='n')
axis(1, at=c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12), labels=c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"), cex.axis=1, las=1)
```

How to reduce the gap between graphs?

Comment: Please specify more exactly what you want to do and where your problems lie - just posting a bunch of code will not raise interest.

Comment: I agree. Plus, your data is somewhat faulty and you don't mention attach.

Answer (score 36):

You can play with the `mai` argument in `?par`. You will have to adjust the left side to get the label in.

I used `par(mfrow=c(1,3), mai = c(1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1))` to create the lower plot.

[image]

[image]

Or you could try using ggplot2.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape)
dm <- melt(d, id.vars = "var8")
dm$var8 <- as.factor(dm$var8)

ggplot(dm, aes(x = var8, y = value, fill = var8)) + 
  theme_bw() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = colors, guide = FALSE) +
  geom_boxplot()+ facet_wrap(~ variable)
```

[image]

Comment: To leave room at the far left for axis labels, but still keeping the plots the same size you can use an outer margin, see the `oma` argument to `par`.

Comment: @Roman Luštrik what about if I have a `par(mfrow = c(2,2)) and want to reduce the vertical space between the columns? not the horizontal one but the vertical one
`

Comment: @Rollo99 perhaps by adjusting the top and bottom margins? Give it a go.

Answer (score 17):

Use larger oma for outer margin area

Use mar for individual plots

```
svg(paste0("comp_pmfs.", tid, ".svg"), width=20, height=10)
par(mar=c(0.5, 0.5, 0.2, 0.2), mfrow=c(1,2),
     oma = c(4, 4, 0.2, 0.2))

plot(d0.exp[,c(1,2)], pch=19, cex.axis=1.9, cex.lab=1.9, type="b", cex=1.3, lwd=5,
    xlim=c(3.5, 15), ylim=c(-0.5, 4))

plot(d12.exp[,c(1,2)], pch=19,
    xlim=c(3.5, 15), ylim=c(-0.5, 4), axes=F, type="b", cex=1.3, lwd=5)
axis(1, at=seq(4, 14, by=2), labels=seq(4, 14, by=2), cex.axis=1.9)
box(lty=1, col="black")

dev.off()
```

[image]

More information can be found here:

http://research.stowers-institute.org/mcm/efg/R/Graphics/Basics/mar-oma/index.htm

Comment: `mai=c(.5,.6,.2,.2)` - margins of each subplot (inches);
`mar=c(2.5,2.5,1,.5)` - additional margins of subplots (lines of text);
`oma=c(1.5,1.5,1.5,.5)` - margins of overall sheet (lines of text);
`mgp=c(1.5,.5,0)` - position of axis name / values / ticks (lines of text).

Comment: The last link is dead, unfortunately.