# Base R plot: Help reducing space in between multiple plots

Tags: r, plot

I have tried to hack around reducing the amount of space between multiple plots in one window but unable to achieve what I want. Plot and code are below. I would like to keep the legend where it is but reduce the space between B and C. How would one move plot C (to the left) close to plot B to mimic the spacing between A and B while keeping the legend in place...I want the legend to stand alone and not inside a plot. P.S. I like the way the basic R plot function plots look and do not intend converting over to using ggplot. [Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LM2hB.png)

```
# p1
par(mfrow=c(1,3))
par(oma = c(1.5,3.5,0,0))
par(mar = c(4,6.5,4,0))
xaxis<-1:7
plot(xaxis, p1, type = "b", pch = 19, col = "red",xlab = "", ylab = "", main = "",ylim = c(1000,30000), xaxt = 'n', yaxt ='n')
points(xaxis, p1.1, col ="blue", pch = 19)
lines(xaxis, p1.1, col = "blue", type ="b")
axis(1, at = 1:7, labels = c(2,4,6,8,10,12,20), las = 1)
axis(2, at = seq(500, 31000, by = 1500), las=2)
mtext("(A)",side=3,line=-1.5, adj = 1,cex=1)
# p2
par(mar = c(4,0.5,4,6))
plot(xaxis, p2, type = "b", pch = 19, col = "red",xlab = "", ylab = "", main = "",ylim = c(1000,30000), xaxt = 'n', yaxt ='n')
points(xaxis, p2.1, col ="blue", pch = 19)
lines(xaxis, p2.1, col = "blue", type ="b")
axis(1, at = 1:7, labels = c(2,4,6,8,10,12,20), las = 1)
mtext("(B)",side=3,line=-1.5, adj = 1,cex=1)
# p3
par(mar = c(4,0.5,4,6))
plot(xaxis, p3, type = "b", pch = 19, col = "red",xlab = "", ylab = "", main = "",ylim = c(1000,30000), xaxt = 'n', yaxt ='n')
points(xaxis, p3.1, col ="blue", pch = 19)
lines(xaxis, p3.1, col = "blue", type ="b")
axis(1, at = 1:7, labels = c(2,4,6,8,10,12,20), las = 1)
mtext("(C)",side=3,line=-1.5, adj = 1,cex=1)

# axes labels
mtext("Y",side=2,line=0,outer = TRUE,cex=1)
mtext("X[enter image description here][1]",side=1,line=0,,cex=1,outer= TRUE, las=0)
legend("right", legend = c("blah 1", "blah 2"),col = c("red", "blue"), bty = "n", xpd=TRUE, mar(c(7,7,7,7)), cex = 1, pch = 19)
```

Comment: The first plot instruction gives *"Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : object 'p1' not found"*.

Answer (score 1):

Remove **all** `par(mar(...))` and use `mai` instead. See [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15848942/how-to-reduce-space-gap-between-multiple-graphs-in-r/25917715) with a solution that uses `mai` and another one that uses `mar`.

```
old_par <- par(
  mfrow = c(1, 3), 
  mai = c(1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1), 
  oma = c(1.5, 3.5, 0, 0)
)

# rest of code is the same

par(old_par)
```

[image]

---

### Test data creation code

```
set.seed(2021)
p1 <- p2 <- p3 <- cumsum(rnorm(7))*10000
p1.1 <- p2.1 <- p3.1 <- cumsum(rnorm(7))*10000
```